# QUARTZ : Both, a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter, are not supported

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using [cron-utils](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils) library for scheduling purpose. When I provide both DoM and DoW then I get following exception

> Both, a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter, are not supported.

I found out that this exception is consistent with QUARTZ specification.
I want to know why it is not supported ? Because it seems to be valid requirement to run something like on "**5th of September only if its on Sunday**"
Do I need to write two separate expression and take its intersection?
What is recommenced solution for this issue?

Comment: If your library doesn't support it, you can't really do anything with it. It is not supported probably becouse it's rare enough edge case that hadn't been covered. For example paste this: 0 0 0 5 * SUN * here http://www.defineyourtimepattern.net/ It turns out that is has very very rare occurences. From my expiriences, cron implementations are tested only to fits the most common expressions and doesn't support when you try to do something fancy
What you can do is to implement it like 0 0 0 5 * * * and check inside a script if it's sunday. Then run your logic.

Comment: The requirement doesn't make sense, which kind of job do you want to trigger only if a certain day in month matches a day of week? Noting that the intersection of those two conditions might not happen in the whole year. I would say behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz does not support the feature. However, this can be achieved in [cron-utils](http://cron-utils.com/) with a custom cron definition. In order to mirror the same definition of [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), but without the restriction regarding day-of-month and day-of-week, you could do this:

```java
CronDefinition cronDefinition =
    CronDefinitionBuilder.defineCron()
        .withSeconds().withValidRange(0, 59).and()
        .withMinutes().withValidRange(0, 59).and()
        .withHours().withValidRange(0, 23).and()
        .withDayOfMonth().withValidRange(1, 31).supportsL().supportsW().supportsLW().supportsQuestionMark().and()
        .withMonth().withValidRange(1, 12).and()
        .withDayOfWeek().withValidRange(1, 7).withMondayDoWValue(2).supportsHash().supportsL().supportsQuestionMark().and()
        .withYear().withValidRange(1970, 2099).withStrictRange().optional().and()
        .instance();

CronParser parser = new CronParser(cronDefinition);
parser.parse("0 0 0 3 * MON#1");
```